# Using jQuery UI draggable, how can I use a callback function on hover over a droppable object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I need to append text to a cloned helper object when it's dragged over a droppable object.

Is there a way to trigger a callback on hover over a droppable object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something to happen when the draggable is over the droppable?

If so, just use the over event:

```
$('.iamdroppable').droppable({

over: function() {  
//do something here
},

});
```

Comment: Awarded answer.  My secondary question was another problem in the draggable drag event.  Removed for clarity.  Thanks again.